# Loading a symbol from db (symbology-style.db)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm working on a Qgis python module. I would like to apply a symbol on a layer by his name entry from the symbology database. I know that some defaults symbols are saved into a sqlite db (symbology-style.db) in table symbol. I have not found how to apply the style loaded from the db on the layer. Someone know ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the QGIS Python console, use the following code, comments in the code :

```py
import os

# instance of the QGIS application
app = QgsApplication.instance()
# path to the user default directory symbology db
path_db = os.path.join(
    app.qgisSettingsDirPath(),
    "symbology-style.db"
)
# new QgsStyle object
sty = QgsStyle()
# load the db
sty.load(path_db)
# get a marker symbol by name
marker_symbol = sty.symbol("diamond red")

# active point layer
point_layer = iface.activeLayer()
# set the new marker symbol to the active layer
point_layer.renderer().setSymbol(marker_symbol)
# refresh the symbology displayed in the canvas
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot !