# Change QGIS symbology-style.db location

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Is it possible to change the location of the symbology-style.db in QGIS? Either through the API on launch or through an environment variable?

Comment: Does this help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353561/loading-a-symbol-from-db-symbology-style-db?

Comment: I did see this. I want to load the whole styles database at QGIS launch so I can make edits to it through the QGIS UI not programmatically